# Is it viable to set up a store only using magento API?

Tags: web-services, api, magento, mule

I am trying to set up a web store using magento on a SOA Architecture. So I intend to use all of the functionalities through the API connecting it with mule ESB.

However on my research I have read that the magento API is Silly Slow. And now I am wondering if it actually can handle the requests of an entire website.

Has anybody done something like this before? Can it actually work? If not, is there a workaround?

Regards
Leo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not viable to setup a store using only Magento's SOAP and RPC APIs. THat is not the intention of these APIs.

Comment: Hi Alan, thanks for your answer. But then, which is the intention of the APIs? What should be done through it?

Comment: To access information and change state in your Magento store in a manner that's (relatively) stable and consistant across Magento versions, and to do so using the existing ecosystem of tools around SOAP and RPC.

Answer (score 0):

There are examples where people have done what you are looking for such as http://www.yireo.com/software/magebridge

They claim to be 40% faster than native Magento.

I've tried the tool, and it is quite functional.